# Using Outer Products and Matrix Multiplication to Compute Tour Weight in Traveling Salesman Problems

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, discrete-optimization, algebraic-graph-theory

## Set up

Let $G$ be a complete, weighted, and directed graph with $N$ vertices as in the asymmetric Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP).  Without loss of generality, let the the vertex set $V$ of $G$ be such that $V = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, N\}$.  Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$.  Then the weight of the edge from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ is $A_{i,j}$.

Let $T$ be a tour of $G$ i.e. a permutation of the vertices of $G$.  For example, $T = \langle 3,1,2 \rangle$ for a graph with $N = 3$ vertices.  The return to the first vertex is implicitly included at the end of the tour. Then the weight $w_T$ of $T$ is then

\begin{equation}
w_T = A_{T_N, T_1} + \sum_{i = 1}^{N-1} A_{T_i,T_{i+1}}.
\end{equation}

## Matrix Multiplication

Now, instead of "indexing into" $A$, another way to get $A_{ij}$ is through multiplication of basis vectors $e_i$ where $e_i$ is zero in all its entries except at index $i$ where it is $1$. For example, $A_{11} = e_1^\intercal A e_1 = \langle 1, 0, \ldots, 0\rangle^\intercal A \langle 1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0\rangle$, and in general $A_{ij} = e_i^\intercal A e_j$.  Therefore, the above equation can be rewritten as

\begin{equation}
w_T = e_{T_N}^\intercal A e_{T_1} + \sum_{i = 1}^{N-1} e_{T_i}^\intercal A e_{T_{i+1}}.
\end{equation}.

## Using the Outer Product

Another way to approach this problem, in some sense, more directly, is through the use of [outer products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).  The first step is create two matrices $E_l, E_r$ defined by

\begin{align}
E_l &= \sum_{i = 1}^N e_i \otimes e_{T_i} \\
E_r &= \sum_{i = 1}^N e_i \otimes e_{T_{i + 1}},
\end{align}

where $T_{N + 1} = T_1$, and $u \otimes v$ is the outer product of $u$ and $v$.  These matrices effectively have the basis vectors $e_{T_j}$ as their columns.  Then, using the [Trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)), the weight of the tour can ***usually*** be succinctly represented as

\begin{equation}
w_T = \mathrm{Tr}\hspace{1pt}(E_l A E_r).
\end{equation}

The problem is that sometimes $E_l$ and $E_r$ have zero-diagonal, which mean so does the resulting matrix $E_l A E_r$, and thus the trace is also equal to zero while the actual weight of the tour is not.

## Example

Consider a TSP whose graph has the adjacency matrix $A$ defined such that

\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 0 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

and tours $T_1 = \langle 1,2,3 \rangle$ and $T_2 = \langle 2,3,1 \rangle$.  These tours result in

\begin{align}
E_{1,l} &= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&
E_{1,r} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \implies& E_{1,l} A E_{1,r} &= \begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 6 & 4 \\
 8 & 0 & 7
\end{bmatrix} \implies& \mathrm{Tr}\hspace{1pt} (E_{1,l} A E_{1,r}) &= 15 \\
%
E_{2,l} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&
E_{2,r} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \implies& E_{2,l} A E_{,r} &= \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 7 & 8 \\
 3 & 0 & 2 \\
 6 & 4 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \implies& \mathrm{Tr}\hspace{1pt} (E_{2,l} A E_{2,r}) &= 0 \\
\end{align}

## Question

Because this formulation works for all the other tours of the 3-vertex instance (using the `Julia` code below), I'm curious why it doesn't work for all of them.  Coincidence?  Additionally, **what would be a way to alter this method to make it work for all tours**?

```
tour: [1, 2, 3] tour weight: 15
tour: [2, 1, 3] tour weight: 15
tour: [3, 2, 1] tour weight: 15
tour: [1, 3, 2] tour weight: 15
tour: [2, 3, 1] tour weight: 0
tour: [3, 1, 2] tour weight: 15
```

## Code

Julia code implementing this method.  The basis-vector outer-products are effectively taken care of with the `stack` function.

```
using LinearAlgebra

function basisVector(dim :: Int, index :: Int) :: Vector
    v = zeros(Int, dim)
    v[index] = 1
    return v
end

function tourWeight(adjacencyMatrix :: Matrix{T}, tour :: Vector{Int}) :: T where T <: Real
    basis = basisVector.(size(adjacencyMatrix)[1], [tour; view(tour, 1)])
    left  = basis[1:end-1] |> stack
    right = basis[2:end]   |> stack
    mat   = left * adjacencyMatrix * right
    return tr(mat)
end

mat = [0 2 3; 4 0 6; 7 8 0]
permutationVector = [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1],[1,3,2],[2,3,1],[3,1,2]]
(tour -> println("tour: $tour tour weight: ", tourWeight(mat, tour))).(permutationVector)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem both in the calculation of your matrices, and in the formula for your sum.

You want $E_l$ to order rows according to the permutation, I think it accomplishes what it does. You want $E_r$ to order columns according to the permutation but shifted by one. Your definition our $E_r$ gives the permutation matrix for the permutation shifted by one, but for swapping columns, you need to transpose it.

If we follow your notations, we should have
\begin{equation}
E_{1, r}= \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
This is the permutation matrix for the permutation $\langle 2,3,1 \rangle$ which is $T_1$ shifted by one.

Then you calculate $w^T = Tr(E_lAE_R^T)$.

Comment: That fixes it!  Thanks so much!  It felt weird there wasn't a transpose in there.